# Jenkins - Bitbucket Team/Project fails to find any repo in Bitbucket Cloud

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Added a new Bitbucket team project in Jenkins (v2.164-2) but it does not find any repos in Bitbucket cloud.

I tried to downgrade Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin to v2.4.4 (from v2.4.6) since I read somewhere it works but did not work for me.

Output of `Scan Organization Folder`:

```
Started by user admin
[Thu Sep 05 17:29:45 UTC 2019] Starting organization scan...
[Thu Sep 05 17:29:45 UTC 2019] Updating actions...
Looking up team details of <team name>...
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using jenkins/****** (Jenkins)
Could not resolve team details
[Thu Sep 05 17:29:45 UTC 2019] Consulting Bitbucket Team/Project
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using jenkins/****** (Jenkins)
Looking up repositories of user <team name>
0 repositories were processed
[Thu Sep 05 17:29:45 UTC 2019] Finished organization scan. Scan took 0.11 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Also, note **Could not resolve team details**

Expected to see a repo with a `Jenkinsfile` but found 0 repositories in my team.

Comment: you check the project you are providing is correct, I had the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installed plugin `Bitbucket Filter Project Trait` to be able to filter based on projects.

Answer (score 2):

A case of successful implementation of Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin against Bitbucket Cloud. "A case", therefore, not tested on every version of Jenkins & the plugin.

- Credential: Set a Jenkins credential of type `Username with password`.
  The  `password` = One of "App Passwords" registered to the user's
  "Personal settings", with right permission for `Projects`,`Repositories`, `Pull Requests` and `Webhook`.
- Owner: Set the value after bitbucket domain meaning, `https://bitbucket.org/<this_value>/`

Then the repositores appeard as dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! After a while, I found a problem with my credentials:
| e-mail (Bitbucket): develop@my-domain.com
| Username (Jenkins/Multibranch pipeline): develop
| Password: One of "App Passwords"