# Cannot add credentials to Jenkins Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I have installed the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin onto my Jenkins server (version 2.249.3) in order to trigger builds on a git push. I've followed all guides I can find, but cannot seem to be able to add my credentials in the drop down menu on build configuration for a multibranch pipeline.

[Selecting credentials for plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGFw.png)

I have a few global credentials saved as shown below - but none of them are showing up in the drop down menu and I can't work out if it's a bug or if I've done something wrong.

[List of credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpPWc.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67315551/9956279 for an example of configuration.